# Mongoose Model.find is not a function - fails in one case works in another

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-middleware

I have two similar parent-child relationship trees in my data model and I am using Mongoose's middleware to handle cascade of deletes.

The first hierarchy is represented as follows:

[blog hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhetY.png)

```
//blog.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./user.js');
var Entry = require('./entry.js');
var Follower = require('./follower.js');

var Blog = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    headerImageUrl: String,
    description:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

Blog.pre('remove', function(next) {
    Entry.find({"blogId": this._id})
        .exec(function(err, entries) {
            console.log("found entries " + entries);
            for(var i = entries.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
                entries[i].remove();
            }
        });
    Follower.remove({"blogId": this._id}).exec();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', Blog);


//entry.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Blog = require('./blog.js');
var Comment = require('./comment.js');

var Entry = new Schema({
    blogId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Blog'
    },
    title: String,
    thumbnailUrl: String,
    content: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

Entry.pre('remove', function(next) {
    Comment.remove({"entryId": this._id}).exec();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', Entry);



//comment.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./user.js');
var Entry = require('./entry.js');
var Post = require('./post.js');

var Comment = new Schema({
    text:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postedBy:  {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    parentComment: this,
    entryId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Entry'
    },
    postId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['BLOG', 'FORUM', 'COMMENT'],
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', Comment);
```

In this case, when remove is called on a blog instance, the `Blog.pre('remove'...` functionality does what it is intended to do and cleans up all children of the blog instance.
The calling code is as follows:

```
blogRouter.route('/:blogId')

//delete a specific blog by blog id:    [OWNER OR ADMIN USER]
.delete(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyBlogOwnerOrAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
    Blog.findById(req.params.blogId, function(err, blog) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        blog.remove();
        res.json(blog);
    });
});
```

I am doing exactly the same thing for the second hierarchy, visually represented here: [forum hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIssr.png) and with the following code:

```
//forum.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./user.js');
var Post = require('./post.js');
var Subscription = require('./subscription.js');

var Forum = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: String,
    moderators: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    ]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

Forum.pre('remove', function(next) {
    Post.find({"forumId": this._id})
        .exec(function(err, posts) {
            console.log("found posts " + posts);
            for(var i = posts.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
                posts[i].remove();
            }
        });
    Subscription.remove({"forumId": this._id}).exec();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Forum', Forum);


//post.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./user.js');
var Forum = require('./forum.js');
var Comment = require('./comment.js');

var Post = new Schema({
    createdBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    postText: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    forumId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Forum'
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

Post.pre('remove', function(next) {
    Comment.remove({"postId": this._id}).exec();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', Post);


//comment.js [SAME AS INCLUDED ABOVE]
```

But in this case, when remove is called on a forum instance, the `Forum.pre('remove'...` functionality causes an error to be thrown: TypeError: Post.find is not a function.  The error is thrown at forum.js line 24 (second line in the Forum.pre(...) block)

The calling code is as follows:

```
forumRouter.route('/:forumId')

//delete forum by id:  [ADMIN]
.delete(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
    Forum.findById(req.params.forumId, function(err, forum) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        forum.remove();
        res.json(forum);
    });
});
```

While I have found instance of this error being thrown in my online research here and elsewhere, the causes there were incorrectly exported models or incorrectly defined schemas.  The Post schema is being used successfully throughout the rest of my code with no issues, it is only this call to Post.find that is causing the error. And in fact, my postRouter code calls the following successfully:

```
postRouter.route('/')

// retrieve all forum posts:  [ALL USERS]
.get(function(req, res, next) {
    Post.find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'forumId',
            model: 'Forum',
            populate: {
                path: 'moderators',
                model: 'User'
            }
        })
        .populate('createdBy')
        .exec(function(err, posts){
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(posts);
        });
});
```

Comment: have you logged what Post actually is in your Forum model?

Comment: Yes, when I make a call to get all posts based on forum ID using my REST API, I see the correct association between Forum and Post, and when I log the post data retrieved by `Post.find({"forumId": ObjectId("<<forum object id>")})` then I get the expected data.  Only throwing the error when called from the `pre('remove'...` function.

Comment: Thats not what i asked. Have you ever done a ```console.log(Post)``` right before the line where Post.find is undefined?

Comment: Gotcha.  Just did and it does seem that Post is not behaving correctly.  When performing console.log(Post) I am getting `{}`    However when I perform console.log(Entry) in the other working example, I get `function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model)) {
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    }
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  }`

Comment: That still does not address the underlying issue...the parent child relationship is the same in both cases, the schema definition is essentially the same in both cases, the calling code is the same in both cases, but in one case it works, and in the other it throws an error.